# Getting "No message available" when calling a REST endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am getting the following error when calling REST API.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-19T04:09:54.363+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/createorganization"
}
```

I am newbie to JWT and just added authentication and authorization code based on a tutorial. I have ´/createorganization´ REST API that I permit all - basically no authentication needed. But I am getting the above error when trying to reach it.

Here is signature of my REST API ->

```
@GetMapping(path = "/createorganization")
public @ResponseBody CustomResponse createOrganization(String orgName, String, String email, String password) throws Exception {....
```

Here is my WebSecurity class with configure method ->

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/createorganization").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
```

And here is my call that I am making from Chrome Browser -

```
http://localhost:8080/createorganization?orgName=abcd&email=john@gmail.com&password=complex
```

I expected /createorganization to be called since it is permitAll() in configure() method.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: are configure base path？

Comment: Sorry, I did not follow your question. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.